# How to determine top x rows with a group by - SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
| Category | Employee | Output |
|:--------:|:--------:|:------:|
|    Top   |     A    |   97   |
|    Mid   |     B    |   50   |
|    Mid   |     C    |   35   |
|    Mid   |     D    |   45   |
|    Low   |     E    |   15   |
|    Low   |     F    |   16   |
|    Top   |     G    |   92   |
|    Top   |     H    |   84   |
|    Mid   |     I    |   49   |
|    Mid   |     J    |   31   |
|    Low   |     K    |   22   |
|    Top   |     L    |   79   |
|    Mid   |     M    |   63   |
|    Mid   |     N    |   33   |
|    Low   |     O    |   19   |
|    Mid   |     P    |   33   |
|    Top   |     Q    |   77   |
|    Top   |     R    |   88   |
|    Low   |     S    |   30   |
|    Mid   |     T    |   53   |
|    Mid   |     U    |   68   |
|    Mid   |     V    |   72   |
|    Mid   |     W    |   66   |
|    Mid   |     X    |   51   |
|    Mid   |     Y    |   35   |
|    Mid   |     Z    |   70   |
```

(The real dataset is much larger, about ~20K Rows)

I am trying to find the top 3 output numbers for each group. Ultimately resulting in a dataset like:

```
| Low | 30 |
|:---:|:--:|
| Low | 22 |
| Low | 19 |
| Mid | 72 |
| Mid | 70 |
| Mid | 68 |
| Top | 97 |
| Top | 92 |
| Top | 88 |
```

I have tried:

```
    SELECT TOP 10
        Category,
        Output

    FROM
        raw_data

    ORDER BY    
        Output DESC
```

But that only lists the top 10 overall, not by category.

Adding

`GROUP BY Category, Count_Placements` obviously does nothing, and I cannot group by `Category` itself.

Sorry there is no SQL Fiddle [like I normally do](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4876561/wundermahn?tab=questions), [it is currently down](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86415/1186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select category, output
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by category order by output desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 3
order by category, output desc
```